# Copying garbled column text in excel

Tags: excel, text, copy-paste, textpad

I have some data coming in column format separated by commas

```
name1,age1,school1,subjects1,location1,dob1,doj1
name2,age2,school2,subjects2,location2,dob2,doj2
name3,age3,school3,subjects3,location3,dob3,doj3
```

some are like this separated by white spaces

```
name4,age4,school4,subjects4,     location4,dob4,    doj4

name5,age5,school5,   subjects5,location5,dob5,doj5
```

How can i copy paste them correctly in separate columns in excel Sheet.
I have tried doing this using **textpad** , by copying it and then replacing the comma by blank space and then selecting the **block select mode** and copying each column seperately and then pasting it.
But process is too cumbersome and time taking.

Comment: do you want even any spaces?

Comment: Do you want to remove white spaces when copy-paste?

Comment: i want that data to be copied in the excel without whitespaces and commas.I mean first element in first columns, second in second and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very easy to do. Select your text and go to Data --> Data Tools --> Text To columns. Then select "Delimited" option and press NEXT. Afterwards, tick "comma" and "space" and press finish. It will do everything in a separate column.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no commas in your data, which would likely be qualified with double quotes, do a Regex Replace.

> Find: `+,`
>
> Replace `,`

Works in TextPad and most any other text editor that can do Regex.